# how to find not exists number in ordered column, oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table and it contains date based data. one of this table of columns is increasing 1 to ...5000. Somedays some of this numbers are missing and i want to find them with db jobs that runs every 5 mins. Can i get this jumping numbers with only one select cursor ?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   (
  SELECT LEVEL AS id
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5000
)
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM your_table)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n74L8qTH)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From your_table order by col;

       COL
----------
         1
         3
         4
         7
         8
```

Query that finds missing values:

```
SQL> select 0 + level val from dual
  2  connect by level <= (select max(col) from your_table)
  3  minus
  4  select col from your_table;

       VAL
----------
         2
         5
         6

SQL>
```